# Why do I have 2 SQLAlchemy connections when pool_size is set to 1?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

Hello I have a telegram bot connected to a MySQL db. I'm using a free account of PythonAnywhere which allows me to have max 3 connections to db per user. But I've been getting a `max_user_connections` error, so I've configured my SQLAlchemy engine like this:

```
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=False, echo_pool=True, pool_size=1, pool_recycle=1200)
```

I was under the impression that with `pool_size=1`, there would be only one connection to db. But there is 2! Can you help me understand why that is?

Here's what `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows me:

[image: processlist]

The first one is the console I'm checking the process list with. But the next two were created as the bot worked.

I also added `max_overflow=0` just to test but that didn't make any difference either.

Comment: How are you running your telegram bot; maybe multiple instances are running?

Answer (score 0):

The only connection to `python-telegram-bot` that I can think of is threads. PTB uses the following threads:

- main thread where you call `updater.start_polling/webhook()` and `updater.idle()`
- One thread for fetching updates (started by `updater.start_polling/webhook()`)
- One thread for processing updates (started by `Dispatcher.start`, calling `dispatcher.process_update`)
- worker threads for `run_async` handlers - by default that's 4 workers, may be customized by the `workers` argument of `Updater/Dispatcher`
- 1 thread for each job in the `JobQueue`

If a new connection is created in each thread, then you might have to think about where you call `create_engine` or so.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainerof `python-telegram-bot`

Answer (score 0):

PythonAnywhere developer here -- I think that the problem is that you're calling `create_engine` at the module level (that is, outside your view function).  When your app is started up, it will run the code inside your module, and then fork off the worker process -- so if you call create_engine outside a function, that will create a connection at that time, and then another will be created when your worker process needs one.

In general I'd recommend against calling `create_engine` from outside views.